How do you configure the python linter and autocompletition with catkin python packages in vscode?
I am having some trouble trying to configure pylint in vscode and the autocompletition tool. They both fail to detect python modules that are installed from another catkin package.
I have tried adding the workspace/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages to python.autoComplete.extraPaths, python.analysis.extraPaths and pylint.args via --init-hook. What am I missing, how have you configured your environment to deal with this?
Many thanks in advance!
